# Google in app billing migration from V2 to V3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an existing app using IAB V2 I would like to update it to V3. I've done some testing and noticed the following:

*When I publish items in the new developer console interface I can buy them with the IAB V3 implementation but with a V2 implementation I get "impossible to buy this item".

*When I publish items in the old developer console interface I can buy them with the IAB V2 implementation but with a V3 implementation I get "impossible to buy this item".

Is it the way it's working or may be I'm doing something wrong, If I want to migrate to version V3 do I have to put items in the new interface only? What about people who have the V2 app, are they going to be able to by items anymore ?

Comment: Have you tried adding items in both console interfaces?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I put items in the old interface, and try to put them in the new one they will be overridden. And I will have the same problems: V2 seeing only old design items and V3 seeing the new design item

Comment: Scary. Thanks for posting this question. I haven't tried this so far. You could have separate item IDs for the two versions, I guess?

Comment: Definitely, hopefully someone who has played with the new version of google IAB could help.

Comment: I'm, erm, _playing_ with it, but unfortunately, not in parallel with V2. But I have come to a conclusion. I want a robust app so I won't rely on something that Google doesn't explicitly specify. So if I were in your shoes, I'd simply use separate items.

Comment: By the way, have you succeeded in testing in-app billing on an AVD emulator?

Comment: No, I'm using a device to test